# How to send email alert notification if SQL query condition is triggered?

Tags: python, sql, azure, databricks, smtplib

Everyday we load data from 6 brands (CONCEPT_CD column with categorical data ['PB','PK','WE','MG','WS' & 'PT']). The idea is to send a notification alert if one of the brands is not received for the day. I haven't arrived at a concrete sql query to detect brand is missing. I am thinking like a, "select count(distinct CONCEPT_CD)<6", then missing brand, send email alert.

But I want to know, how you can use a SQL query and then consequently use the SQL result to generate an Email notification if missing brands are detected?
We use Databricks Notebook and Azure ADF. This is my first time working in setting up alerts. Any help would be appreciated. Can furbish extra details if needed.

Comment: Does Azure have ability send an e-mail? If not you must use external trigger function for sending e-mail.

Comment: @SergeyZaykov Azure may not have an explicit function to send email, but I believe we can use Databricks Notebook & use some function to send email. Then attach this to Pipeline in Data Factory.

Comment: For example, PostgeSQL can use extrenal trigger function written by C. C program can send e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

How to detect absent brands

```sql
VALUES ('PB'),('PK'),('WE'),('MG'),('WS'),('PT')
EXCEPT 
SELECT CONCEPT_CD FROM "your table" WHERE "load date" = TODAY
```